# Manage non-packages with NPM, Bower, etc?

Tags: node.js, package, npm, bower, package-managers

Can NPM, Bower, or any similar Node.js based frameworks download non-"packages" for my project?

I try to keep external libraries out of my repo as much as possible by having something like NPM download them for me (and then ignoring them in my repo).

However, every so often I run across something which doesn't have a package.json or anything similar. It's just one fixed file, either a zip or a random file.

Thanks.

Comment: Does Keeping external libraries out of your repo mean no git/svn externals?

Comment: @JonSurrell Ideally, yes. I always try to make it so the repo only contains 100% my own files. That way I know I can edit any file in there without accidentally editing a third-party file that could cause conflicts down the line. For example, even for a WordPress project, none of the WordPress core files are kept in my repo. I use either composer or NPM to download and integrate them with my project at build time, then keep them from getting committed by adding them all to a .ignore file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower can [install](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install) arbitrary files from a URL. This URL can point to a single file or an archive (which will be exploded).
For example:

```
bower install http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js
```

Or in you bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "funcunit": "https://github.com/bitovi/funcunit/archive/jmvc.tar.gz"
}
```

In addition, Bower will also be able to install a package from a Github repository even if it does not contain a bower.json file. It will simply checkout the entire tag/branch.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm much more familiar with NPM, so I didn't know bower was able to do that... guess it's time to start added bower to all my projects as well. =)